# Refer the cell value of an excel sheet with another excel sheet by giving environmental variable path

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel worksheets, 
The first is:

> Test.xlsx

and the second:

> Sample.xlsx

I'm referring the `B10` cell value in the Test.xlsx with the `C10` of Sample.xlsx using the formula:

```
='C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\Work[Sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!C10
```

in the `B10` of Test.xlsx file.

Can anyone suggest me how to replace the hard coded path of the destination file in the formula:

`("C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\Work")`

with an environmental variable "Temp" with the value `"C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\Work"`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 files: Book1.xlsx and Book2.xlsx
Go to the Book2.xlsx and special cell and type "`=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$5`" for example.
When you change the value in Book1.xlsx.A5 and save, Book2.xlsx takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your temp path is stored on cell E1. on B10 enter:

```
=INDIRECT(E1&"!C10")
```

Of course you can use the name Temp instead of E1 . Just name the E1 cell (or any other cell you desire) Temp and change the formula to :

```
=INDIRECT(Temp&"!C10")
```

- To name the cell click on it and change the name in the box on the left top side[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use VBA to expand environment variables. If the folder is always on the user's desktop then something like this might suffice. Place this into a standard code module in your workbook:

```vb
Public Function GetEnviron(strEnv As String, Optional folderAppend As String = vbNullString) As String

    If Not folderAppend = vbNullString Then
        folderAppend = folderAppend & IIf(Right(folderAppend, 1) = "\", vbNullString, "\")
    End If

    GetEnviron = Environ(UCase(strEnv)) & "\" & folderAppend

End Function
```

And in your spreadsheet use like:

```vb
=INDIRECT("'"&GetEnviron("USERPROFILE","Desktop\Work\")&"[Sample.xlsx]Sheet1'!C10")
```

---

The `Environ()` function in VBA is used to expand environment variable strings - so for example:

- Environment variable: `%USERPROFILE%` | Returns: (C:\Users\[username])

  - VBA `Environ("USERPROFILE")` | Returns: (C:\Users\[username])
- Environment variable: `%APPDATA%` | Returns: (C:\users\[username]\AppData\Roaming)

  - VBA `Environ("APPDATA")` | Returns: (C:\users\[username]\AppData\Roaming)